# How does the tag cleanup process work?

Tags: discussion, tags

I know the Stack Overflow community does a good job of keeping the tagging system clean.  How do you go about doing tag cleanup?

Do you do an aggregate count of how many posts that have a tag?  Then identify a set of tag-synonyms and merge them together by retagging with the tags in the set that has the largest number of posts?

Or is there more to it than that?

Answer (score 4):

Tag requests are mostly managed through Meta; if you come across a tag that needs cleanup, you can post a question here with [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) and explain what needs to be done and why. If you find a tag that really just shouldn't exist, you can use [burnination-request](/questions/tagged/burnination-request) to request its removal.

From there, the community provides input on your thoughts and, if a consensus is reached, one of two things will likely happen:

1. A few willing people will manually (or with the help of some userscripts) retag and clean up questions in the tag(s) you have listed.
2. A moderator will take it into his/her own hands and use moderation privileges to instantly synonymize/destroy/blacklist the tag(s).

We have [a few guidelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/258672) to follow when dealing with retags, but most of what you need to know can be found in the [FAQ index](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow) under "Tagging" and the wikis of the tags listed above.

Comment: Note that obvious mis-tagged/typo tags do not need this process. You just retag them.