How does [cobra] explicitly mean three things?
Somebody went through the effort of describing three different technologies for the tag cobra.
The excerpt reads:

Three possible technologies:
The Cobra toolkit is a pure Java HTML parser and rendering engine with support for CSS 2 and JavaScript.
The Cobra Programming Language has Python-like syntax that targets the .NET runtime and supports built-in unit tests, contracts and both dynamic/static programming support.
Cobra is a Go library for creating powerful modern CLI applications as well as a program to generate applications and command files.

The tag wiki describes the three in more detail.
Not only did someone write this, but others approved the edit, and multiple authors contributed and improved the text. I cannot think of a more obvious misuse of the tag system.
Obviously we need to split this tag into three different ones. There currently are only 55 questions that use this tag.
Funnily enough, I found this tag on a question about a MATLAB toolbox, a fourth meaning for the tag!

Asking the obvious: Tagging a question with [tag:go]  and [tag:cobra] (similar for the other usages) can't work?

@rene A tag is supposed to mean one thing. You can combine tags like [go] and [string]. But here [string] means one thing, it plays the same role if you combine it with [java] or [python].

Yeah, I agree on that. Just wanted to make sure we're on the same page.

If the question is "how did multiple Stack Overflow users agree on doing something counter to the Meta policy consensus?", well, you might want to sit down for the rest of this....

@KarlKnechtel LOL. Yeah, I know enough not to wonder about what goes on in others’ heads. :)

looks to me like they understand it's a mess, but are somehow discouraged from cleaning up the mess or even calling attention to it, so they put up a warning triangle  and some directions to anyone driving by

personally, I only ever answer questions, never/rarely ask them, because I'm deeply uncomfortable starting a question, especially on meta. I can totally understand if someone doesn't know how to navigate Meta, how to figure out the "red tape" (tags and whatnot), which gods to pray to (who can do something about it, what's expected of you, ...).

good example right here: "easy clean-up by retagging", ok great, but who can do that, how do they do it, how do they get notified of this, and do we get notified when it's done? as someone who doesn't hang out here and doesn't know about most of the housekeeping, I would think I'm expected to go through all the questions in the tag and edit them individually... or google until I find a greasemonkey userscript for that. I guess that's all written somewhere and I just don't know how to find the information... or maybe it does require osmosis and lots of participation to pick up?

@Christoph https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/280836/7328782

also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250933/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work so now I'm sure it's connected to O(n) of manual work, as it should, for quality reasons

There seem to be quite a few questions related to a Python package called CobraPy, and at least one about a Julia package called Cobra. These are meanings #5 and #6. People really are inventive with project names, eh?

For that matter, there's also a risk of people mistyping [tag:corba] and hitting a valid tag by mistake...

Suggested title: "The tag [Cobra] speaks with a forked tongue".

@AndrewGrimm The tag should be made tag synonym of [tag:Hydra]

Wait, the programming language appears to have been discontinued 10 years ago, do we really have (many) questions about it? OTOH, there is a COBRApy library, I think 8 out of the 9 cobra+python questions are about it (although it seems irrelevant for at least 1). The remaining one is about converting code to the Cobra language, it has no answer and seems a bit useless now.

There are also 6 java+cobra questions. If we exclude [tag:go], [tag:python] and [tag:java], this gives just 4 questions: 1 for [tag:julia], 1 for [tag:matlab], 1 for [tag:.htaccess] (??)… and just 1 actually mentioning the programming language (but not asking something about it).

There already is go-cobra and lobo-cobra so that is an easy clean-up by retagging the concerning questions.
A practical way to do this is:

Fix each question and its answers: edit to improve, close, delete, up/down vote so all content in that tag is up to par

First remove the cobra tag and add go-cobra for all posts tagged go+cobra [COMPLETE]

replace cobra with lobo-cobra when applicable in the remaining posts [COMPLETE]

remove cobra from posts where non of the intended usage of the tag are applicable [COMPLETE]

Update the tag wiki and excerpt to reflect the new meaning of the tag [COMPLETE]

flag this answer for a moderator and ask them to rename the cobra to cobra-lang (see below) [COMPLETE]


NOTE: Edits, even tag edits, bump a post which is annoying for tag followers, specially in low-traffic tags. In that case spread out the editing over a few days.
I'm not sure how much we like adding -lang to a tag but maybe renaming to cobra-lang can prevent future mis-tagging.
The wiki and excerpt can then be updated to its single meaning.
I think this is the path forward with the least friction.

I've added extra guidance and a plan of approach which I think cover all the issues you raised. Let me know if there are  things unclear.

I think we should do point 5 before point 4. Temporarily having a [cobra] tag that only refers to the language is probably fine, but having a [cobra-lang] tag with three different meanings is confusing at best.

I've renamed [cobra] to [cobra-lang] for clarity going forward. Might still need some cleanup, but hopefully less prone to misuse now.

@Machavity you jumped then gun? I'm not going to annoy the folks in Go. I'd like to keep using this site.

"I'm not sure how much we like adding -lang" - Irrelevant, what we like is to complain about it so you can't win either way :) I like to refer to Go as Golang / Go-lang because "Go" is as generic a word as it can get (and using golang seems to do quite well in Google searches as well), but ho boy do purists get curled toes. "No! The name is Go!". So I can assume that when you would introduce cobra-lang you'd get people shouting "Cobraaaaaaa!". If you get that reference, you were built in a very good year / decade.

@Gimby Knowing is half the battle

I think the excerpt can have some warning, to decrease the probability of mis-tagging by users.

@Machavity, I think you might have been a bit too fast, I only found 2 questions that seem to be related to (but not about) the programming language. This language has been discontinued for 10 years now…

@Machavity I found that [tag:lobo] and [tag:lobo-cobra] are both very small (5 and 11 questions, some have both tags). I'm not sure it makes sense to have both tags, considering one is a component of the other, and Lobo itself is not at all an active project (most portions of the web site are down, the last question was posted in 2014). I would merge these two tags.
