Curses, [cursor]! Should we burninate and break the spell?
I saw a question with the cursor tag. The tag wiki states:

DO NOT USE. This tag is ambiguous.

This tag is clearly very broad, and adds no value to questions. Oftentimes it is used to talk about the user's mouse-controlled cursor, in which case the tag wiki states mouse-cursor or caret would be more appropriate. Furthermore, this can add ambiguity to a question, making it harder to determine what type of cursor the OP is referring to.
When I originally came across the question with the "cursor" tag, I actually thought it might be referring to the Cursor app. I suppose there is an argument for the tag wiki existing to help users choose other tags, but the existence of the tag itself only promotes the usage and therefore ambiguization of questions. I think there has to be a better way, for this tag and more generally, to indicate that other tags should not be used than leaving it with a "do not use" wiki.
The Burnination Criteria
Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?
This would never be the sole tag used on a question - if it was, that would be IT-support related, and therefore off-topic for SO. In addition, if cursor is used, it is arguable that caret or mouse would be a better choice. It is ambiguous - does it refer to a database cursor? The app? The computer item?
Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
Yes.
Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
No. This is superfluous - it could be argued that it adds info about specifically the GUI cursor, but in that situation mouse-cursor is more specific and applicable. This tag is too broad to add meaningful information, and furthermore is part of several other tags (e.g. mouse-cursor) so a new user would choose one of those instead.
Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?
To a layperson, yes. To a coder, this is again too broad to be useful - the Tag Wiki says:

cursor can mean many things, and it is recommended to use more specific tags.


"Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? Yes." - I'd actually say otherwise. As you suggested above, a lot of uses for this tag could be off-topic. A hypothetical question tagged with nothing but [cursor] seems way more likely to be an OS/UI/UX question than a programming one.

@Anerdw I disagree: my first thought was of the SQL CURSOR; at a glance, almost all the SO questions with the tag are in some way related to the programming aspect of cursors, such as a disappearing cursor in Swing, a misbehaving cursor in GDI, styling cursors in CSS and similar. While off-topic use is certainly possible, it doesn't seem to be the majority of uses.

If the tag is on-topic, but the major issue with it is that it is ambiguous, then we need a tag disambiguation (and probably a synonym afterwards), not a burnination.

the tag wiki does have a link to here in the markdown Split [cursor] into more specific tags

@ChristophRackwitz You have it backward. Only one criteria must be met for a tag to stay. The four burnination criteria must all be met in order to burninate the tag. If one criterion is not met, the tag cannot be burninated.

mouse pointer (cursor), caret (cursor), result thingy for database queries (cursor)... the multiple sets of eyeballs this tag attracts will be mostly disappointed that it's not their concept of a cursor. disambiguation might be helpful but the existence of this tag helps nobody (IMHO). -- so let me be backwards a different way and say, working backwards from the conclusion that the tag has to go (if that is consensus/majority opinion), we'll have to justify why all four criteria for keeping it should not be considered satisfied

With nearly 7,000 questions tagged, disambiguating would be a big effort for this one

There have been some big ones over the years, @zcoop98 . The problem is more likely a lack of interest from curators to do so. The recent changes to tags really don't help make things like this easier either.

Considering the results from this SEDE it might seem better™ to correct any posts tagged with [[tag:cursor]] that aren't about [[tag:database-cursor]]s to the correct tag, and then make [[tag:cursor]] a synonym of [[tag:database-cursor]]. I would suggest, if it can be batched, that any tagged with [[tag:android]] and [[tag:cursor]] have the tag changed to [[tag:android-cursor]], if it isn't already tagged with it (and removed if not).

the effort of retagging could be reduced with some userscripts that provide a good UI/UX for these operation. I am not invested enough in the tag to bother writing one for this.

@ThomA [[tag:android-cursor]], by its description, is nothing but a database cursor. I cannot imagine why that's supposed to be anything special just because android is involved. IMHO that should be [[tag:database-cursor]] + [[tag:android]]

A fair assessment, @ChristophRackwitz . I don't know anything about Android development to tell if it's different.

From a [cursor]y glance, this looks in need of disambiguation

@elechris "[Cursor]s! Foiled again!"

Tags need not be "stand alone". Other tags might give the context.

Just wanted to chime in to say that this is the worst pun for these tag burnination posts ever seen.

@SyedM.Sannan thank you. I do my best.

Based on your own criteria arguments, this does not qualify for burnination, since it does not fail all four:

A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for burnination.

Aside from that, the concept of each meaning of cursor is ostensibly on-topic in their own right; there can be and are valid, on-topic questions about:

working with SQL cursors

changing the appearance of the mouse cursor

adjusting the caret size


for example. I don't know about the Cursor web tool but it could theoretically have an on-topic question about programming some day.

Thus, the appropriate action here would be tag disambiguation, not tag burnination.

"A tag must fail ALL of those tests in order to be considered for burnination." There's plenty of tags that have been burninated that don't meet all four requirements. competitive-coding and htc, for example. I do agree that retagging / disambiguation is still a better option though.

The convention of requiring all four criteria seems pretty silly. If it's agreed that a tag "adds no meaningful information to the post", why would any of the other criteria matter?

@khelwood Maybe so, but you'll need to get community and mod support to change the process.

Sorry, I’m pretty new to SO - since the tag wiki already talks about using other tags, what does the further disambiguation process consist of?

@MrDeveloper A post here on Meta that requests tag disambiguation be considered and proposes new tags for each of the separate meanings of the tag that are on-topic, and burnination of the tag for uses that are not on-topic, generally. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/430222/how-does-cobra-explicitly-mean-three-things for a recent example.

@khelwood A tag that adds no meaningful information might be useless, but this does not automatically mean it is worth to spend any effort on, or in particular to dedicate the attention of the community to it. If you find a question where you can replace the tag with something more meaningful, go ahead and do that, but it's just a normal edit. There is no need for a concerted community effort. See the full quote of Shog about "pointless busywork".

@Bergi The other criteria are not judging whether it's worth spending effort on.

@Bergi I agree. Fixing from the perspective of tags means touching a whole lot of questions which do not really deserve time to be spent on them. With the limited amount of curation capability available, that does not make sense. Only questions which deserve curation attention should be touched. But... quite a lot of people just can't ignore a tag being wrong on the site. It must die.

@Gimby Your personal opinion on whether it's worth it to fix tags on some of the questions doesn't change the fact that the ruleset in place for burnination precludes doing that in this case. I'm also concerned you seem to be assuming it's not worth it to fix tags on any/all of these questions without looking at them, unless you've actually already gone through every single one?

@Bergi Whether disambiguation is worthwhile in this case is another matter. My answer only addresses that, if anything is to be done, it needs to be disambiguation, not burnination, based on the current rules.

@TylerH makes sense - I don't think this tag is worth disambiguation though because it's not a drawback from the question. It might be confusing, but can make some sense for questions...

@TylerH Oh I totally agree that this tag should be disambiguated (probably as suggested in the comments by synonymising it to [[tag:database-cursor]] and cleaning up every that doesn't fit that). I was only responding to khelwood about the silliness of the burnination criteria.
